# setTimeout am I doing it wrong? for fireworks

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

So I am trying to get the clearInterval to work. This is from: https://codepen.io/whqet/pen/Auzch (I modified it a bit to make it more towards what I needed. Essentially, I want the animation to cease after 10000 ms. Excuse the messy coding, I threw in a timer at the bottom so I could see whether or not it would work.. Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks!

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById( 'canvas' ),
  ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' ),
  // full screen dimensions
  cw = window.innerWidth,
  ch = window.innerHeight,
  // firework collection
  fireworks = [],
  // particle collection
  particles = [],
  // starting hue
  hue = 120,
  // when launching fireworks with a click, too many get launched at once without a limiter, one launch per 5 loop ticks
  limiterTotal = 5,
  limiterTick = 0,
  // this will time the auto launches of fireworks, one launch per 60 loop ticks
  timerTotal = 60,
  timerTick = 0,
  mousedown = false,
  // mouse x coordinate,
  mx,
  // mouse y coordinate
  my;
  
// set canvas dimensions
canvas.width = cw;
canvas.height = ch;
// now we are going to setup our function placeholders for the entire demo
// get a random number within a range
function random( min, max ) {
 return Math.random() * ( max - min ) + min;
}
// calculate the distance between two points
function calculateDistance( p1x, p1y, p2x, p2y ) {
 var xDistance = p1x - p2x,
   yDistance = p1y - p2y;
 return Math.sqrt( Math.pow( xDistance, 2 ) + Math.pow( yDistance, 2 ) );
}
// create firework
function Firework( sx, sy, tx, ty ) {
 // actual coordinates
 this.x = sx;
 this.y = sy;
 // starting coordinates
 this.sx = sx;
 this.sy = sy;
 // target coordinates
 this.tx = tx;
 this.ty = ty;
 // distance from starting point to target
 this.distanceToTarget = calculateDistance( sx, sy, tx, ty );
 this.distanceTraveled = 0;
 // track the past coordinates of each firework to create a trail effect, increase the coordinate count to create more prominent trails
 this.coordinates = [];
 this.coordinateCount = 3;
 // populate initial coordinate collection with the current coordinates
 while( this.coordinateCount-- ) {
  this.coordinates.push( [ this.x, this.y ] );
 }
 this.angle = Math.atan2( ty - sy, tx - sx );
 this.speed = 2;
 this.acceleration = 1.05;
 this.brightness = random( 50, 70 );
 // circle target indicator radius
 this.targetRadius = 1;
}
// update firework
Firework.prototype.update = function( index ) {
 // remove last item in coordinates array
 this.coordinates.pop();
 // add current coordinates to the start of the array
 this.coordinates.unshift( [ this.x, this.y ] );
 
 // cycle the circle target indicator radius
 if( this.targetRadius < 8 ) {
  this.targetRadius += 0.3;
 } else {
  this.targetRadius = 1;
 }
 
 // speed up the firework
 this.speed *= this.acceleration;
 
 // get the current velocities based on angle and speed
 var vx = Math.cos( this.angle ) * this.speed,
   vy = Math.sin( this.angle ) * this.speed;
 // how far will the firework have traveled with velocities applied?
 this.distanceTraveled = calculateDistance( this.sx, this.sy, this.x + vx, this.y + vy );
 
 // if the distance traveled, including velocities, is greater than the initial distance to the target, then the target has been reached
 if( this.distanceTraveled >= this.distanceToTarget ) {
  createParticles( this.tx, this.ty );
  // remove the firework, use the index passed into the update function to determine which to remove
  fireworks.splice( index, 1 );
 } else {
  // target not reached, keep traveling
  this.x += vx;
  this.y += vy;
 }
}
// draw firework
Firework.prototype.draw = function() {
 ctx.beginPath();
 // move to the last tracked coordinate in the set, then draw a line to the current x and y
 ctx.moveTo( this.coordinates[ this.coordinates.length - 1][ 0 ], this.coordinates[ this.coordinates.length - 1][ 1 ] );
 ctx.lineTo( this.x, this.y );
 ctx.strokeStyle = 'hsl(' + hue + ', 100%, ' + this.brightness + '%)';
 ctx.stroke();
 
 ctx.beginPath();
 // draw the target for this firework with a pulsing circle
 ctx.arc( this.tx, this.ty, this.targetRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2 );
 ctx.stroke();
}
// create particle
function Particle( x, y ) {
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 // track the past coordinates of each particle to create a trail effect, increase the coordinate count to create more prominent trails
 this.coordinates = [];
 this.coordinateCount = 5;
 while( this.coordinateCount-- ) {
  this.coordinates.push( [ this.x, this.y ] );
 }
 // set a random angle in all possible directions, in radians
 this.angle = random( 0, Math.PI * 2 );
 this.speed = random( 1, 10 );
 // friction will slow the particle down
 this.friction = 0.95;
 // gravity will be applied and pull the particle down
 this.gravity = 1;
 // set the hue to a random number +-50 of the overall hue variable
 this.hue = random( hue - 50, hue + 50 );
 this.brightness = random( 50, 80 );
 this.alpha = 1;
 // set how fast the particle fades out
 this.decay = random( 0.015, 0.03 );
}
// update particle
Particle.prototype.update = function( index ) {
 // remove last item in coordinates array
 this.coordinates.pop();
 // add current coordinates to the start of the array
 this.coordinates.unshift( [ this.x, this.y ] );
 // slow down the particle
 this.speed *= this.friction;
 // apply velocity
 this.x += Math.cos( this.angle ) * this.speed;
 this.y += Math.sin( this.angle ) * this.speed + this.gravity;
 // fade out the particle
 this.alpha -= this.decay;
 
 // remove the particle once the alpha is low enough, based on the passed in index
 if( this.alpha <= this.decay ) {
  particles.splice( index, 1 );
 }
}
// draw particle
Particle.prototype.draw = function() {
 ctx. beginPath();
 // move to the last tracked coordinates in the set, then draw a line to the current x and y
 ctx.moveTo( this.coordinates[ this.coordinates.length - 1 ][ 0 ], this.coordinates[ this.coordinates.length - 1 ][ 1 ] );
 ctx.lineTo( this.x, this.y );
 ctx.strokeStyle = 'hsla(' + this.hue + ', 100%, ' + this.brightness + '%, ' + this.alpha + ')';
 ctx.stroke();
}
// create particle group/explosion
function createParticles( x, y ) {
 // increase the particle count for a bigger explosion, beware of the canvas performance hit with the increased particles though
 var particleCount = 300;
 while( particleCount-- ) {
  particles.push( new Particle( x, y ) );
 }
}
// main demo loop
function loop() {
 
 // this function will run endlessly with requestAnimationFrame
 requestAnimFrame( loop );
 
 // increase the hue to get different colored fireworks over time
 //hue += 0.5;
  
  // create random color
  hue= random(0, 360 );
 
 // normally, clearRect() would be used to clear the canvas
 // we want to create a trailing effect though
 // setting the composite operation to destination-out will allow us to clear the canvas at a specific opacity, rather than wiping it entirely
 ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
 // decrease the alpha property to create more prominent trails
 ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';
 ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, cw, ch );
 // change the composite operation back to our main mode
 // lighter creates bright highlight points as the fireworks and particles overlap each other
 ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';
 
 // loop over each firework, draw it, update it
 var i = fireworks.length;
 while( i-- ) {
  fireworks[ i ].draw();
  fireworks[ i ].update( i );
 }
 
 // loop over each particle, draw it, update it
 var i = particles.length;
 while( i-- ) {
  particles[ i ].draw();
  particles[ i ].update( i );
 }
 
 // launch fireworks automatically to random coordinates, when the mouse isn't down
 if( timerTick >= timerTotal ) {
  if( !mousedown ) {
   // start the firework at the bottom middle of the screen, then set the random target coordinates, the random y coordinates will be set within the range of the top half of the screen
   fireworks.push( new Firework( cw / 2, ch, random( 0, cw ), random( 0, ch / 2 ) ) );
   timerTick = 0;
  }
 } else {
  timerTick++;
 }
 
 // limit the rate at which fireworks get launched when mouse is down
 if( limiterTick >= limiterTotal ) {
  if( mousedown ) {
   // start the firework at the bottom middle of the screen, then set the current mouse coordinates as the target
   fireworks.push( new Firework( cw / 2, ch, mx, my ) );
   limiterTick = 0;
  }
 } else {
  limiterTick++;
 }
}
// mouse event bindings
// update the mouse coordinates on mousemove
canvas.addEventListener( 'mousemove', function( e ) {
 mx = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
 my = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
});
// toggle mousedown state and prevent canvas from being selected
canvas.addEventListener( 'mousedown', function( e ) {
 e.preventDefault();
 mousedown = true;
});
canvas.addEventListener( 'mouseup', function( e ) {
 e.preventDefault();
 mousedown = false;
});
// once the window loads, we are ready for some fireworks!
window.onload = loop;

 // when animating on canvas, it is best to use requestAnimationFrame instead of setTimeout or setInterval

window.requestAnimFrame = ( function() {
 return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function( ) {
     window.setTimeout( timePeriodms );
    }; 
    function stopFireworks () {
     var timePeriodms = 10000;
     window.clearTimeout(timePeriodms);
    };
})();
// now we will setup our basic variables for the demo
  var minute    = 0;
  var sec = 00;
  var zeroPholder = 0;
  var counterIdv2 = setInterval(function(){
                    countUp2();
                  }, 1000);
  function countUp2 () {
      sec++;
      if(sec == 60){
        sec = 00;
        minute = minute + 1;
      }
      if (minute == 0 && sec == 1) {
                    document.getElementById('count-up-2').style.color = 'red';
      }
      if (minute == 0 && sec == 59) {
                    document.getElementById('count-up-2').style.color = 'blue';
      }
       if (minute == 10 && sec == 00) {
                    document.getElementById('count-up-2').style.color = 'red';
      }
      if(sec == 10){
          zeroPholder = '';
      }else
      if(sec == 00){
          zeroPholder = 0;
      }
      document.getElementById("count-up-2").innerText = minute+':'+zeroPholder+sec;
  }
```

```css
body {
 background: #000;
 margin: 0;
}
canvas {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas">Canvas is not supported in your browser.</canvas>
  <table border="1" style="border-color:black;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color: #fff; padding: 5px;"><span>Time spent on page:&nbsp;</span><span id="count-up-2">0:00</span>
       </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: credit: https://codepen.io/whqet (original creator of the fireworks)

Comment: `clearTimeout` expects to be given a timeout object (whatever they're called), not the milliseconds used on the timeout creation.  So that's one issue.  The second issue is that `timePeriodms` is scoped too low in the first place, so it would be unavailable inside the `stopFireworks` method

Comment: Start the fireworks, then use setTimeOut to call a function that will stop it after the desired time.

Comment: So I've added the setTimeout, and moved it so it's scoped higher. However, now the animation does not display at all...

Answer (score 0):

### [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) callback's argument

When [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) calls the callback function it supplies a high precision time in ms. You can use this time to control the timing of your animations.

For example the following animation loop will stop 10 seconds after the first frame is called.

```
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
var startTime;
const endTime = 10000;  // in ms 
function mainLoop(time) { 
    if (startTime === undefined) { startTime = time }
    if (time - startTime > endTime) {
         console.log("Animation end.");
         return;
    } 
    // draw animated content

    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
```

This gives you better timing control in animations than using `setTimeout` especially if you have more than one thing to control the timing of (see demo)

### Demo

The demo uses the same method to count down the time and control the fireworks. A few seconds before the end the fireworks are held back and then a second before a group are fired to explode in time with zero (Well there about!!!)

```js
// Code based loosely on OPs code in so far as it animates fireworks.
// There is no control of fireworks via mouse.
// Uses reusable buffers to avoid GC overhead in low end devices.


const ctx = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
const GRAVITY = 0.2;  // per frame squared
var cw = canvas.width = innerWidth - 40;
var ch = canvas.height = 500; 
const iH = innerHeight;

var startTime;

const DISPLAY_TIME = 10000;    // in ms. Time to countdown

const SHELL_X = cw / 2;  // Location that shells are fired from in px
const SHELL_Y = ch;
const SHELL_TIME = 100;        // in frames
const MAX_SHELLS = 8;        
const MAX_PARTICLES = 1000;    // Approx max particles.      
const SHELL_RANDOM_RATE = 0.01; // cof of shell random fire control
const SHELL_FIRE_CURVE = 3;    // Highest power of fire control exponents 
var randomFire = 0;            // holds the odds of a random shell being fired


Math.TAU = Math.PI * 2;
Math.PI90 = Math.PI / 2;
Math.PI270 = Math.PI + Math.PI90;
Math.rand = (m, M) => Math.random() * (M - m) + m;
Math.distance = (x1, y1, x2, y2) => ((x1 - x2) ** 2 + (y1 - y2) ** 2) ** 0.5;

requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);



function mainLoop(time) {
    if (startTime === undefined) { startTime = time }
    const timer = DISPLAY_TIME - (time - startTime);
    const displayTime = timer / 1000 | 0;
    if (timer <= 0) {
        countdown.textContent = "HAPPY NEW YEAR 2020";
        if(particles.size === 0 && shells.size === 0) {
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
            shells.clear();
            startTime = undefined;
            countdown.textContent = "Click to restart";
            canvas.addEventListener("click",() => requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop), {once: true});

            return; // ends update
         } else {
            randomFire = 0;  // pervent shells firing after zero time
         }
    } else {
        countdown.textContent !== displayTime && (countdown.textContent = displayTime);
    }
    

    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.2;
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000"
    ctx.fillRect( 0, 0, cw, ch );
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';
    shells.update();
    particles.update();
    
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    shells.draw();
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    particles.draw();
    
    if (timer < 2500 && timer > 1000) { randomFire = 0 }
    else if(timer <= 1000 && timer > 0) { randomFire = 1 }

    if(shells.size < MAX_SHELLS && particles.size < MAX_PARTICLES) {
        if(Math.random() < randomFire ** SHELL_FIRE_CURVE) {
            randomFire = 0;
            shells.fire(
                Math.rand(cw * (1/3), cw *(2/3)),
                Math.rand(iH * (3/4), iH *(4/4)),
                SHELL_TIME
            );
        }
        randomFire += SHELL_RANDOM_RATE;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}



function Trail() {}
function Particle() { }
function Shell( sx, sy, tx, ty ) {
    this.trail = new Trail();
    this.init(sx, sy,tx,sy);
}
Trail.prototype = {
    init(x, y) {
        this.x1 = this.x2 = this.x3 = x;
        this.y1 = this.y2 = this.y3 = y;
    },
    update(x, y) {
        this.x3 = this.x2
        this.y3 = this.y2
        this.x2 = this.x1
        this.y2 = this.y1
        this.x1 = x;
        this.y1 = y;
    },
    draw() {
        ctx.moveTo(this.x1, this.y1);
        ctx.lineTo(this.x2, this.y2);
        ctx.lineTo(this.x3, this.y3);
    }
};
Shell.prototype = {
    init(x, y, time) {  
        this.x = SHELL_X;
        this.y = SHELL_Y;
        this.sx = (x - this.x) / (time / 2);
        this.sy = ((y - this.y) * (GRAVITY / ((time) ** 0.5)))* 2;
        this.power = (-this.sy * 10) | 0;
        this.hue = Math.rand(360, 720) % 360 | 0;
        this.active = true;
        this.trail.init(this.x, this.y);
        this.time = time  / 2;
        this.life = time / 2;
    },
    explode() {
        this.active = false;
        particles.explode(this, this.power);
    },
    update() {
        this.time -= 1;
        if (this.time <= 0) { this.explode() }
        this.sy += GRAVITY;
        this.x += this.sx;
        this.y += this.sy;
        this.trail.update(this.x, this.y);
        return this.active;
    },
    draw() {
        ctx.strokeStyle = `hsl(${this.hue},100%,${(this.time / this.life) * 100}%)`;
        ctx.beginPath();
        this.trail.draw();
        ctx.stroke();
    },
};
Particle.prototype = {
    init(shell) {
        this.x2 = this.x1 = this.x = shell.x;
        this.y2 = this.y1 = this.y = shell.y;
        this.dx = shell.sx;
        this.dy = shell.sy;
        this.angle = Math.rand(0, Math.TAU);
        const zAng = Math.cos(Math.random() ** 2 * Math.PI)
        this.speed = zAng * shell.power / 30;
        this.friction = 0.95;
        this.gravity = GRAVITY;
        this.hue = (Math.rand(shell.hue - 5, shell.hue + 5) + 360) % 360;
        this.brightness = Math.rand( 25, 50 );
        this.alpha = shell.power / 10;
        this.decay = Math.rand( 0.2, 0.5);
        this.active = true;
    },
    update() {
        const dx = Math.cos(this.angle);
        const dy = Math.sin(this.angle);
        this.x2 = this.x1;
        this.y2 = this.y1;
        this.x1 = this.x - dx;
        this.y1 = this.y + dy;
        this.speed *= this.friction;
        this.x += (this.dx *= 0.9);
        this.y += (this.dy *= 0.9);
        this.dy += GRAVITY / 100;
        this.x += dx * this.speed;
        this.y += dy * this.speed;
        this.alpha -= this.decay;
        if( this.alpha <= 0 || this.x < 0 || this.y < 0 || this.x > cw) {
            this.active = false;
        }
        return this.active;
    },
    draw() {
        const alpha = this.alpha / 5 > 1 ? 1 : this.alpha / 5;
        const lum = this.brightness + this.alpha
        ctx.strokeStyle = `hsla(${this.hue},100%,${lum<100 ? lum : 100}%,${alpha})`;
        ctx. beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo( this.x2, this.y2);
        ctx.lineTo( this.x, this.y );
        ctx.stroke();
    }
};
function BubbleArray(extension) {
    return Object.assign([], { 
            size: 0,
            update() {
                var read = 0, write = 0; 
                while (read < this.size) {
                    const item = this[read];
                    if(read !== write) {
                        const temp = this[write]
                        this[write] = item;
                        this[read] = temp;
                    }
                    item.update() === true && (write ++);
                    read++;
                }
                this.size = write;
            },
            draw() {
                var i = 0,len = this.size;
                while(i < len) { this[i++].draw() }
            },
            add(item) {
                this.size ++;
                this.push(item);
            },
            clear() { this.length = this.size = 0 },
            getInactive() { return this.size < this.length ? this[this.size++] : undefined },
        },
        extension,
    );
}
const particles = BubbleArray({
    explode(shell, count) {
        var item;
        while(count-- > 0) {
            !(item = this.getInactive()) && this.add(item = new Particle());
            item.init(shell);
        }
    },
});
const shells = BubbleArray({
    fire(tx = mx, ty = my) {
        var item;
        !(item = this.getInactive()) && this.add(item = new Shell());
        item.init(tx, ty, 100);
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    padding: 0px;
}
canvas {
    background: #000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
#countdown {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: xx-large;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<div id="countdown"></div>
```